# Argument “r” in math subarray environment not working

Tags: alignment, arguments

While studying LaTeX, I find that the results of following codes

```
\[
\sum_{\begin{subarray}{c}
    i<n\\ i+j=k
    \end{subarray}} = 
\sum_{\begin{subarray}{l}
    i<n\\ i+j=k
    \end{subarray}} =
\sum_{\begin{subarray}{r}
    i<n\\ i+j=k
    \end{subarray}}
\]
```

is

[image]

**It seems that argument *'r'* doesn't work. What's the reason?**

Comment: Hi and welcome. You will most likely get better help if you provide a complete compilable code example.

Comment: As far as I can see from the source code `subarray` only tests for `c` and everything else will be treated as left aligned.

Comment: @mickep Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subarray` only supports `c` and takes whatever else for left alignment.

```
% amsmath.sty, line 1031:
\newenvironment{subarray}[1]{%
  \vcenter\bgroup
  \Let@ \restore@math@cr \default@tag
  \baselineskip\fontdimen10 \scriptfont\tw@
  \advance\baselineskip\fontdimen12 \scriptfont\tw@
  \lineskip\thr@@\fontdimen8 \scriptfont\thr@@
  \lineskiplimit\lineskip
  \ialign\bgroup\ifx c#1\hfil\fi
    $\m@th\scriptstyle##$\hfil\crcr
}{%
  \crcr\egroup\egroup
}
```

The idea is that `\hfil` at the left is only added if the argument is `c`. Any other value would be ignored.

We can add use a better test: the `\hfil` is added conditionally on the argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\subarrayfill}{mm}
 {
  \str_if_in:nnT { #1 } { #2 } { \hfil }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{subarray}[1]{%
  \vcenter\bgroup
  \Let@ \restore@math@cr \default@tag
  \baselineskip\fontdimen10 \scriptfont\tw@
  \advance\baselineskip\fontdimen12 \scriptfont\tw@
  \lineskip\thr@@\fontdimen8 \scriptfont\thr@@
  \lineskiplimit\lineskip
  \ialign\bgroup
    \subarrayfill{cr}{#1}% add \hfil if center or right alignment
    $\m@th\scriptstyle##$%
    \subarrayfill{cl}{#1}% add \hfil if center or left alignment
    \crcr
}{%
  \crcr\egroup\egroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\sum_{\begin{subarray}{c}
    i<n\\ i+j=k
    \end{subarray}} = 
\sum_{\begin{subarray}{l}
    i<n\\ i+j=k
    \end{subarray}} =
\sum_{\begin{subarray}{r}
    i<n\\ i+j=k
    \end{subarray}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

One might also add a check for the argument to be one of `rcl`.

Extending the idea we could enrich `\substack` with an optional argument (default `c`)

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\substack}{O{c}m}{%
  \begin{subarray}{#1}#2\end{subarray}%
}
```

and we could input the above display as

```
\[
\sum_{\substack{i<n\\ i+j=k}}
=
\sum_{\substack[l]{i<n\\ i+j=k}}
=
\sum_{\substack[r]{i<n\\ i+j=k}}
\]
```

However, as this changes the syntax for `\substack` it might not be a good choice.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: Really appreciated for your answer! I'll continue to study LaTeX and then completely understand all you codes!